# how to delete data from db using id - generated_key

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, web-applications

Please help me to resolve the same problem: I do not know how to delete data from table by id that is auto generated in mysql, I think that this problem can be resolved using GENERATED_KEY in JBDC, all in all I do not know, help me with info how to delete by table id.

table 'note':

```
CREATE TABLE `note` (
`id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`noteName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
`note` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here I am getting value now it is - 'noteName' but it is incorrect I need to get id for every row in a table

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
ResultSet resultSet;
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM note");
while (rs.next()) { 
%>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td id="noteName"><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
        <td>time</td>
        <td id="close">
            <a href=deleteData?id=<%=rs.getString(1) %>><button onclick="deleteRow()" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
%>
```

Here I am deleting data:

```
public class deleteData extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evernoteDB",
                "evernoteDB", "0633739768z");

        String query = "DELETE FROM note WHERE noteName = ?";
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        statement.setInt(1, value);
        statement.executeUpdate();

        response.sendRedirect("/userNotes.jsp");

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify (let alone delete) data from an HTTP `GET`; you should use `POST` (i.e. `doPost`) for that purpose.

Comment: Post payload aside what is happening? Is it that you don't know what the Id is?

Comment: So you don't know how to get the column `0` instead of `1`?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get all data from table.

```
<tr>
    <td><%= rs.getInt("id") %></td> returns id
    <td><%= rs.getString("notename") %></td> returns noteName
    <td><%= rs.getString("note") %></td> returns note
</tr>
```

And change

```
<a href=deleteData?id=<%=rs.getString(1) %>>...</a>
```

to

```
<a href=deleteData?id=<%= rs.getInt("id") %>>...</a>
```

And in servlet change query to

`"DELETE FROM note WHERE id = ?"`

Comment: It is not  right answer, because I don't have column id this column is auto generated by mysql when I am trying to `rs.getInt(1)` I have SQL Exception that: Invalid value for getInt() - 'hello world!' u see it is trying ti get value from string column not from id

Comment: Can you tell me what is value of auto generated field `id` in table? I think it will be like 1,2,3,4... as it's `mediumint`.

Comment: I cannot because, I cannot to get(id) this value, column 1 - it is "noteName"

Comment: You mean to say you don't have column `ID` in table.

Comment: you can see to my table in the top of this question

Comment: Try using `rs.getInt("id");`

Comment: `PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);` will not return generated key while deleting if you use insert it will return generated key.